YouTube Downloader with PHP
I have some problem with my (https://smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/vdown) youtube downloader website.
First, when i enter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exXNEDZDuwc like the image in below
https://i.sstatic.net/pqEqP.png
The size is not showing and i can't download the video.
But when i enter second link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SHAKxIBuH8 . It's working properly like the image in below
https://i.sstatic.net/pqEqP.png
So, my question is how can i do to resolve the problem ? What can i do ?
My source code is available in https://smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/vdown.zip
Thanks a lot :)

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is but it seems like YouTube has been updating their video stream recently. 
I'd suggest to try to add "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0" to the header file of any requests you are using.

Which file i should put in?

And... Could you give me details?
